# Java, checking the right format

Tags: java

I want to check if an input matches my decimal format. I am getting an error "int cannot be dereferenced".
This is what I tried:

```
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("$#.##");

int money= kbdInput.nextInt();

if(money.matches("$#.##")){do sth}
```

Comment: `int`s would never match that format. `String`s might. (But in that case `$` is special, check regexps.)

Comment: Please take some efforts to format your code.

Comment: You want to check if an *int* has a floating point value? You should rethink that.

Answer (score 0):

You can first read input as string, and then, if it matches a format (using `.matches` method of string), use `Integer.parseInt` and continue.

For that format you can try this:

```
s.matches("\\$[0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]")
```

Comment: This would be better regex: `"\\$\\d\\.\\d{2}"`. Your one wouldn't compile with Java.